# freemarker assign by reference or by value? Has it any disadvantages?

Tags: java, freemarker

I am working on a project which uses ftl.
Iam using <#assign> widely so I am wondering how safe it is to use it all the time. Is it storing by reference or by value? The problem is that I assign in a for loop continuously a matrix or a table. I am not sure if I am right using it but it may lead my system to crash. Is it close related to the Heap or the Stack of Java? My data handle is massive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `#assign` does doesn't mater. What matters is if what operators are you using to manipulate those matrixes. FreeMarker operators assume that all data structures (like `List`-s or `Map`-s) are immutable, and so they don't modify the backing (wrapped) `List`-s or `Map`-s. But if you call Java methods on those objects, it depends on the methods you call. Like if yo call `put(key, value)` on a `Map`, then that `Map` will be modified. (But by default FreeMarker doesn't even expose the Java methods of `Map`-s and `List`-s. Templates shouldn't modify the data-model in general, so FreeMarker makes that reasonably hard to do accidentally.)

Comment: could you give some reference to the statement "FreeMarker operators assume that all data structures (like List-s or Map-s) are immutable," . I was trying to find any reference doc , but couldn't find any.

Comment: The FAQ discusses this: http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_modify_seq_and_map